# How I can find out what size solar panels I will need in order to power a single air conditioner?

Tags: air-conditioning, solar-panels

I am thinking to buy an air conditioner, but I want to power it using solar power in order to avoid increasing my personal CO2 emissions.

I am thinking to buy a small 9000BTU one and for personal reasons (living with my parent and we share electricity with other people as well), I want to use solar panels to power it. Looking for the energy classification that device is, I found out that is an A+++ one as shown below:

[image: Device Energy Classification]

So how much power should the solar panel provide, if we assume that I'll install it in Greece at Attica Province.

Comment: Is this "try to offset the usage" or "actually power it directly"? There is a huge difference, because powering directly (or "off grid") means you need to oversize the solar so that it provides enough power most of the time **and/or** significant battery backup (and without batteries it won't run at all at night, obviously). On the other hand, "offset the usage" means matching overall solar input per average year with overall A/C power needed per average year, **and** being able to send electricity back out to the grid (which requires extra equipment and utility cooperation).

Comment: I want to "actually power it directly" no grid

Comment: _"I want to power it using solar power in order to avoid increasing my personal CO2 emissions"_ -- as a general rule, panels have a long enough service life that this works. But if you are serious about that as the goal, you definitely need to take into account the CO2 emissions (and other environmental impacts!) of the manufacture of the panels, and make sure that the panels you acquire are going to save enough in emissions of their service life to offset not just the energy the A/C uses, but also the impacts of making the panels.

Answer (score 3):

For direct solar/off-grid usage, you will likely do much better with a unit designed for DC instead of AC. [Something like this](https://www.hotspotenergy.com/DC-air-conditioner/) - (I have no connection to this company, just the first one from a Google search for *dc powered air conditioner*.) You will need (whether purchased together or separately):

- DC-powered air conditioner
- Solar panels
- Batteries (otherwise you will be limiting usage to only the sunniest parts of the day)
- Controller to tie it all together.

In general, you want the highest efficiency air conditioner you can afford. Most list SEER or a similar rating, but you can also just calculate BTU (= cooling power) vs. the amount of power (W or kW) used when running.

It is quite possible that, due to the efficiencies of mass-production, that a 9,000 BTU AC-powered air conditioner (the kind you can get at any Home Depot, Lowes, Walmart, Costco, etc. or equivalent around the world) will be a **lot** less expensive than a 9,000 BTU DC-powered air conditioner. However, by the time you add in conversion losses (DC to AC) and the associated larger solar, battery, etc. I have a feeling you will be better off with DC.

To find something like this locally available, check with any solar panel providers and also try marine (boat) equipment as that will often be designed to run on DC as well.

Comment: Would never have thought of DC air conditioners.  Thanks for improving my knowledge.

Comment: In Greece that thing is not available, it will cost me more to buy one of these and have them shipped in Greece!!! The most common is the Inverter ones that I have no Idea whether use AC or DC.

Comment: Sometimes it is obvious - e.g., if it says 240V (or 220V or anything between 120V (which you won't see because that is for USA/Canada) and 250V) then it is definitely AC. If it is something less than 100V (typically 12V, 24V or 48V) then it is DC. *Default* will be AC. I downloaded the manual for the one you listed in order to eventually find electrical connection details that were clearly for AC.

Answer (score 1):

A challenge you may face is that some kinds of motors require higher current to get them started than to keep them running. This higher starting current creates a need for other parts of the system to have more capacity than one would expect based on the "rated current" marked on the air conditioner. The DC-to-AC power inverter would need to have a "peak rating" wattage 2-3 times higher than the rated/operating current of the air conditioner. Also, this peak power has to come from somewhere. The usual thing is to include batteries in the system: when the inverter's DC power need goes above what the solar panels can provide in that moment the power is drawn from the battery instead. To make the system work with no battery will require extra solar panels (it's hard to guess how many extra).

This effect will probably be less of a problem with a DC-powered air conditioner. Likewise, an "inverter type" AC-powered air conditioner should also be easier to start than an ordinary non-inverter air conditioner.